# Why truncate when we had to pass a 'w' as an extra parameter to open in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am learning Ruby using the book **Learn Ruby the Hard Way** by Zed Shaw. I am stuck at **Exercise 16: Reading and Writing Files**, because I don't understand why we had to pass a **'w'** as an extra parameter to **open** in Ruby and also called the **truncate** method later on the same file.

**Here's the code sample**

```
puts "Opening the file..."
target = open(filename, 'w')

puts "Truncating the file.  Goodbye!"
target.truncate(0)
```

Any form of help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, using the **'w'** mode will tell Ruby to create a new file with the name you give to it, or it will completely overwrite any file that already has that name. This means it will replace everything in the existing file with whatever text that you give it.

While you can also overwrite the contents of a file using the **truncate()** method, with **truncate()**, you can declare how much of the file you want to remove, based on where you're currently at in the file. Without parameters (`truncate()`) or with a parameter of 0 (`truncate(0)`), **truncate()** acts like **'w'**, whereas **'w'** always just wipes the whole file clean, **truncate()** helps you specify how much content of the file that you want to wipe.

So this line of code`target = open(filename, 'w')`, reads the file with the name `filename` and writes to it as well (it completely wipes the contents of this file). Also, the line `target.truncate(0)` also wipes the contents of this file with the filename `filename`.

In order words, the both methods **'w'** and **truncate()** are doing the same operation of wiping the whole contents of the file. But **Zed Shaw** intuitively used the both of them in the exercise, and asked that research be conducted about why he used the both of them the same time, so that one can understand how the both methods are used, and that both of the methods perform similar operations.

Just to add as a form of extra knowledge, using the **'a'** mode will still tell Ruby to create a new file with the name you give to it if that file doesn't exist already. But unlike the **'w'** mode, if that file does exist, Ruby will start writing at the end of the file, so that you won't lose anything that's already there.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**